# github pages (.github.io) not loading in Firefox and chrome web browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, github-pages

I have noticed that github's page (websites with the ".github.io" url extension) doesn't load on Firefox and Chrome web browsers, except Opera. Both on mobile an desktop.

I have tried diffrent website URLs:

1. xeroxism.github.io
2. praisearts.github.io
3. drivenotepad.github.io

## On chrome and firefox:

[image: github page on firefox and chrome]

2

[image: another github page]

## But on Opera:

[image: functioning github page]

2

[image: another functioning github page]

pleaseeee Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I just tested now and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your browsers and check if proxies are working perfectly.
Try to clean catches.

I have used opera, safari, chrome, internet explorer, Microsoft edge, Firefox and some other browsers on Linux, Windows and Mac OS. But I didn't find such problem even I have explored **Github Pages** on these browsers.

Probably, The problems may be with proxy or some network settings. Check your firewall as well. If these solutions don't work, try to update your Operating System.

Thank You

Comment: I have cleared caches. updated to latest versions of chrome ad firefox...STILL NOT WORKING!  (I use Ubuntu Linux 16LTS)

Comment: Did you update your OS? If not, then you can update using this command: sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 0):

try to clear your cache browser
this can fix

Answer (score -1):

open cmd

```
ipconfig/flusdns
ipconfig/release
ipconfig/renew
```

restart your pc
restart your router/wifi hub/etc......
enter your desired site

Comment: Could you provide more information on what these commands do?